# A map on Jacobians coming from a correspondence explicitly

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, jacobians

From [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/221339/do-all-simple-factors-of-jacobians-of-curves-come-from-correspondences?rq=1) question, we know that every map of the form $J(C) \to J(C)$ for a curve $C$ and it's jacobian $J(C)$ comes from a correspondence between $C\times C$ and in fact we can take this correspondence as a divisor on $C\times C$.

Now, let us take a map $f: C\to D$ of curves and consider the induced map $\pi: J(C) \to J(D) \to J(C)$ which is a projection onto a factor. What correspondence does it correspond to, or more precisely, what is the divisor $X \subset C\times C$ with maps $\alpha,\beta: X \to C$ such that $\pi = \beta_*\alpha^*$?

Comment: $X=$ the inverse image of the diagonal in $D\times D$ by the map $(f,f):C\times C\rightarrow D\times D$.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about that too.

Comment: Note that $X$ is not unique: you can add fibres of the projections and principal divisors on $C\times C$ without changing the induced $\pi$.  But @abx's $X$ is a good choice.